# ScrollView not working in react-native app, content disappears when attempting to add flex and flexGrow

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, scrollview

for some reason a ScrollView in one of my components isn't working despite working in every other component I've implemented it in. Attempting to implement solutions to similar problems seems to just make  the content I want displayed disappear.

I'm expecting to have a scrollable list of sample restaurant dishes. I created some dummy data to pass in for now but noticed it didn't scroll after reaching the end of the phone screen.

```
const testFoods = [
  {
    title: "test",
    description: "Lorem Ipsum",
    price: "$7.77",
    image: "dummyLink",
  },
// Same as above but 4 more times, didn't want to clog up the description
];

export default function MenuItems() {
  return (
    <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
      {testFoods.map((food, index) => (
        <View key={index}>
          <View style={styles.menuItemStyle}>
            <FoodDetails food={food} />
            <FoodImage food={food} />
          </View>
        </View>
      ))}
    </ScrollView>
  );
}

const FoodDetails = (props) => (
  <View style={{ width: 240, justifyContent: "space-evenly" }}>
    <Text style={styles.titleStyle}>{props.food.title}</Text>
    <Text>{props.food.description}</Text>
    <Text>{props.food.price}</Text>
  </View>
);

const FoodImage = (props) => (
  <View>
    <Image
      source={{ uri: props.food.image }}
      style={{
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        borderRadius: 8,
      }}
    />
  </View>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  menuItemStyle: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    margin: 20,
  },

  titleStyle: {
    fontSize: 19,
    fontWeight: "600",
  },
});
```

The result is like so
[Result with code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZqNo.png)
The Header component with the sample restaurant image is a separate component by the way.

I have more data that can't be seen as for whatever reason the screen refuses to scroll. I'm using my actual phone for the tests but the result is the same when I use an emulator, scrolling doesn't work. After looking online I thought I would try adding a parent View with flex: 1 and a flexGrow: 1 to contentContainerStyle inside the ScrollView like so.

```
export default function MenuItems() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <ScrollView
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
      >
        {testFoods.map((food, index) => (
          <View key={index} style={styles.menuItemStyle}>
            <FoodDetails food={food} />
            <FoodImage food={food} />
          </View>
        ))}
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
}
```

But that only resulted in the content disappearing. Reloading the app didn't change anything either [Result after trying above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqyBY.png)

Attempting to use a FlatList had the same result. I've also read that having percentage based styling values on height for any of the children components can make the scrolling stop working but all my components don't utilize such. Oddly enough when I change the styling on the outer view to height: 400, I'm able to get the scrolling to work but this is very sloppy and will likely only work on phone screens similar to mine. I know the ScrollView component is working fine, as when I add "horizontal" to it the scrolling works just fine and I'm able to scroll to the last item in the dataset. Obviously all the content is horizontal now though. [After adding horizontal too ScrollView, scrolling works fine horizontally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYMAN.png)

Any ideas? Could it be some part of my styling I'm not noticing? I'm unable to test this on IOS so I'm not sure if it's an Android specific problem, would be strange though as scrolling worked fine in my other components.

Here's also the Header component code just in case it could be anything in there, although It shouldn't be.

```
const testImage =
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ef/Restaurant_N%C3%A4sinneula.jpg/800px-Restaurant_N%C3%A4sinneula.jpg";

const testTitle = "Sample Restaurant";

const testDescription = "Thai · Comfort · $$ ·  · 4 ⭐ (217+)";

export default function About() {
  return (
    <View>
      <RestaurantImage image={testImage} />
      <RestaurantTitle title={testTitle} />
      <RestaurantDescription description={testDescription} />
    </View>
  );
}

const RestaurantImage = (props) => (
  <Image source={{ uri: props.image }} style={{ width: "100%", height: 180 }} />
);

const RestaurantTitle = (props) => (
  <Text
    style={{
      fontSize: 29,
      fontWeight: "600",
      marginTop: 10,
      marginHorizontal: 15,
    }}
  >
    {props.title}
  </Text>
);

const RestaurantDescription = (props) => (
  <Text
    style={{
      marginTop: 10,
      marginHorizontal: 15,
      fontWeight: "400",
      fontSize: 15.5,
    }}
  >
    {props.description}
  </Text>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your card with TouchableOpacity.

```
<TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0} key={index} style={styles.menuItemStyle}>
    <FoodDetails food={food} />
    <FoodImage food={food} />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

I hope this thing will work.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but sadly it didn't work. I appreciate the answer however.

Comment: Total how many items are present list?
If item's are fit to screen then scroll will not work. it should contain more than the screen size.
Please check that scrollview is imported from react-native or other.(it should be from react-native.)